# Catel and TCP connections

Tags: c#, mvvm, catel

I am building an application in catel which should be capable of connecting to a TCP server and receive data from it.
I am struggling on where to implement the connection mechanics and the callback of the received data. I also was unable to find a good example on how to implement such a functionality. Has anybody a link or hint how I could start?

Comment: Have you tried anything, or perhaps **Googled it?** Many interesting articles will come up. Also, have you **tried putting together and code yet?**

Comment: Yes, I googled a lot, but did not find anything usable by the time I posted my question. By now I found https://github.com/bigN13/ChatApplication which helped a lot

Comment: That's great :)